# Pymssql program works on mac but but not on windows

Tags: python, windows, macos, pymssql

I have a piece of code that works like a charm if I run the program on a mac (MBA running mavericks).  If i move the code to a windows box (windows server 2008 R2 64 bit) i get an error on the SQL query itself (show below).  The error indicates that there is a syntax error near the ",".

The code that I am running is below:

```
    try:
      cur.execute("SELECT * FROM dbo.IPAM_Node as A \
        FULL OUTER JOIN IPAM_NodeAttrData as B ON A.IPNodeId = B.IPNodeId \
        FULL OUTER JOIN IPAM_Group as C on A.SubnetId = C.GroupId \
        FULL OUTER JOIN IPAM_GroupAttrData as D on C.GroupId = D.GroupId \
        WHERE IPAddress IN (%s);",(Hosts_as_Tuples,))
      allrows = cur.fetchall()
      print 'allrows:', allrows
```

This code did not work on the MAC until i added the "," at the end of the "WHERE" clause.  This is where the windows library seems to be objecting.  I have tried taking the "," out and the program runs OK but it does not evaluate the tuple properly.

I have tried various suggestions such as using """ - to no avail or change in behavior.

The run time error is show below:

```
C:\SFTP_Root\v1.0.1.d\Model>[07/Nov/2013:12:25:27] ENGINE Listening for SIGTERM.

[07/Nov/2013:12:25:27] ENGINE Bus STARTING
[07/Nov/2013:12:25:27] ENGINE Set handler for console events.
CherryPy Checker:
The Application mounted at '' has an empty config.

[07/Nov/2013:12:25:27] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Autoreloader'.
[07/Nov/2013:12:25:27] ENGINE Started monitor thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
[07/Nov/2013:12:25:27] ENGINE Serving on 10.188.49.151:4444
[07/Nov/2013:12:25:27] ENGINE Bus STARTED
it is NOT a list
Host List: ['10.188.49.0', '10.188.49.1', '10.188.49.2', '10.188.49.3']
**DATABASE ERROR: (102, "Incorrect syntax near ','.DB-Lib error message 102, sever
ity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")**
144.131.52.107 - - [07/Nov/2013:12:25:38] "GET /ip/informationservice/?ipaddress
=10.188.49.0/30 HTTP/1.1" 200 346 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.
9; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
```

According to the **version** method the libraries in both places are on the same version.  As below:

On the Mac:

```
isp-pc:site-packages matingara$ python
Python 2.7.5 (v2.7.5:ab05e7dd2788, May 13 2013, 13:18:45)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pymssql
>>> pymssql.__version__
'2.0.0'
>>>
```

On Windows (two versions of python tried):

```
C:\Python27>python.exe
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pymssql
>>> pymssql.__version__
'2.0.0'
>>>

C:\Python27>python.exe
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pymssql
>>> pymssql.__version__
'2.0.1'
>>>
```

Comment: yes - i know.  i was having trouble getting the page to accept my code - it said "indent by four spaces" - so i took it literally.  the 'try' block is just fine in the script itself!

Comment: as i have said, the code works fine on the mac and throws the error only on windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the messages on the sql server?  (Is the database connection okay on both machines?)

Also, have you tried evaluating the string before calling execute?  Something like:

```
queryString = "SELECT * FROM dbo.IPAM_Node as A \
    FULL OUTER JOIN IPAM_NodeAttrData as B ON A.IPNodeId = B.IPNodeId \
    FULL OUTER JOIN IPAM_Group as C on A.SubnetId = C.GroupId \
    FULL OUTER JOIN IPAM_GroupAttrData as D on C.GroupId = D.GroupId \
    WHERE IPAddress IN (%s);" % (Hosts_as_Tuples,)

print queryString

cur.execute(queryString)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Adam!  I have tried the queryString idea and it does not change the behavior.  However, I will try it again.  I have also tried the queryString over multiple lines without the "\" continuation character and enclosed in triple quotes """.

Comment: Also, I know the database connection is working find as other methods in the same code work just fine.  Also, if i remove the trailing "," after (Hosts_as_Tuples) the query works but the cur.fetchall() will only ever return one row!

Comment: i will also look on the sql server and see what messages are there.

Comment: The sql server messages will probably be your best bet for pinpointing what's causing the issue.

Comment: In the end.  Using the querystring idea and getting it correct did fix this problem in both the mad dev and windows operational enviroment!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Adam and a consultation with and SQL guru here, we managed to prove that the evaluation of the %s seems to work differently on mac and pc.

so, i restructured the code as follows (similar to what Adam suggested - but slightly different):

```
try:
  sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM dbo.IPAM_Node as A \
    FULL OUTER JOIN IPAM_NodeAttrData as B ON A.IPNodeId = B.IPNodeId \
    FULL OUTER JOIN IPAM_Group as C on A.SubnetId = C.GroupId \
    FULL OUTER JOIN IPAM_GroupAttrData as D on C.GroupId = D.GroupId \
    WHERE IPAddress IN " + str(Hosts_as_Tuples) + ";" 
  cur.execute(sqlQuery)
```

in other words, i built up the query by concatenating several strings.  This now works on windows!